# Laughably tiny random engine

Tags: c++, random, hashcode

I devised a tiny pseudo-random engine and I wondered if it would be considered decent or even good.

It is based on a SHA256 implementation and uses a single 32-bytes state variable.

On seeding, the seed is hashed and that's the initial state of the engine. Then, for each new pseudo-random number, the state is hashed, its first byte is popped and the first byte of the hash is pushed at the end of the state (...as in "shifting left").

The requested pseudo-random number is extracted directly from the <strike>state</strike> hashed state (e.g. a 64-bits integer can be served from the first 4 bytes of the <strike>state variable</strike> hashed state).

All this is based on the assumption that SHA256 produces "uniform" distribution (i.e. for an infinite number of distinct inputs, the occurence of 1 or 0 for every bit of the hash is very close to 50%).

Here is my C++ implementation (please ignore the `util::` namespace; the SHA256 implementation I use [can be found here](https://github.com/System-Glitch/SHA256)):

> random_engine.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SHA256/SHA256.h>
#include <array>

namespace util {

    class random_engine_t {
    private:

        std::array<uint8_t, 32>
            m_state;

    public:

        random_engine_t(const uint8_t* seed, size_t slen);

        random_engine_t(const char* seed);

        random_engine_t(const time_t seed);

        template<typename T>
        T next() {
            static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 32);

            SHA256 sha; sha.update(m_state.data(), m_state.size());
            uint8_t* digest = sha.digest();
            T t = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(digest);
            //update seed
            {
                //shuffle back
                for (size_t s = 1; s < m_state.size(); s++) {
                    m_state[s - 1] = m_state[s];
                }
                //set last byte from digest
                m_state[m_state.size() - 1] = digest[0];
            }
            delete[] digest;
            return t;
        }
    };
}
```

> random_engine.cpp

```
#include <util/random_engine_t.h>

namespace util {

    random_engine_t::random_engine_t(const uint8_t* seed, size_t slen) {
        SHA256 sha; sha.update(seed, slen);
        uint8_t* digest = sha.digest();//initial state
        {
            std::copy(digest, digest + 32, m_state.data());
        }
        delete[] digest;
    }

    random_engine_t::random_engine_t(const char* seed) :
        random_engine_t(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(seed), strlen(seed)) {}

    random_engine_t::random_engine_t(const time_t seed) :
        random_engine_t(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&seed), sizeof(time_t)) {}
}
```

The `next()` function is templated but is meant only for *integer* types.

Is there any obvious flaw with this design that I'm not seeing ?

Comment: Calling into an entire SHA256 is not particularly "tiny"

Comment: Nor is allocating memory from the global allocator every time you want a random number.

Comment: @Reinderien The SHA256 algorithm is not that complex, it can be implemented in around a hundred lines of code, see [this version from Brad Conte](https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/blob/master/sha256.c).

Comment: Ah, I'm used to OpenSSL where merely creating a digest object has overhead, but it seems the SHA256 implementation OP references does not. But you are right about the allocation done by `SHA256::digest()`; that's unfortunate.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Complexity is relative. Quality aside, [libc typically implements rand() in about two lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4768189/313768).

Comment: @Reinderien True, `rand()` is laughably tiny *and* laughably bad :)

Comment: @Reinderien (and @G.Sliepen), that looks like an observation that would make a good Answer...

Comment: @Reinderien: If you want short and simple, and also still fairly good, xoroshiro256++ or `**` has the same state size, and is cheaper to compute.  Just a couple 64-bit rotates and shifts, a few XORs, and a couple additions.  https://prng.di.unimi.it/ / https://prng.di.unimi.it/xoshiro256plusplus.c

Comment: If I understand your algorithm correctly, once I've called your next() function 32 time I have a completed knowledge of the engine inner state. Are you sure this is a desirable feature?

Comment: This is a bit too short for a full answer, but you may want to consider changing the interface to implement the [UniformRandomBitGenerator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator) requirements so that your engine can be used with the standard distributions from `<random>`.

Comment: The observation of @YSC is important. If this is not intended as a secure PRNG then it's is *much* slower than something like xoroshiro256++. If it is intended to be secure then it appears the output completely leaks the internal state.

Comment: To get rid of announcing inner state, you could simply use first byte for inner state while serving the rest as the random number. In sha individual bytes are not corrolated. Also in order assert the performance, at least to a degree, you could save a large number of random bytes and then try to compress the file using highest compression setting with a good algorithm like lzma2. If it compresses, it is not a good algorithm. A good RNG should be indistinguishable from white noise which will never compress. That said this test will be an indicator, not a definite answer.

Comment: "Engine" is not the correct word for this; it is a "pseudorandom number generator".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Possibility of short cycles

SHA256 is a cryptographically secure hash function, which indeed means the output is very uncorrelated to the input. However, given exactly the same input, it will always give the same output. That implies that if, after a while, the state will return to an earlier value, you will have entered a cycle. If this cycle is short, then the quality of your random number generator has also dropped significantly.

Note that the probability that you enter a cycle is 100%, the only question is how long it will take given the initial seed, and how long the cycle will be.

One way prevent short cycles from happening is to ensure the state is not updated based on the hash function itself. If you would just treat the state as a 256 bit counter, and increment the counter by 1 each time `next()` is called, you are guaranteed to have the longest possible cycle (\$2^{256}\$).
See also [this Cryptography question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/does-a-hash-function-in-chaining-mode-or-in-counter-mode-make-a-better-pseudo-ra).

## Unsafe use of `reinterpret_cast<>()`

You should not use `reinterpret_cast<>()` to create a `T` from `m_state`. Consider that `T` might have different alignment restrictions than `m_state`, for example `T` might be a 64-bit integer or floating point number. Instead, create a default-constructed `T` and `std::copy()` the memory from `m_state` into `t`. Also note that all of this is only legal if `T` is a [trivial type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType), so you might want to add a `static_assert()` or restrict the template parameter to verify that.

## Make more use of STL algorithms

You are already using `std::copy()` in the constructor, you can also use it to shift the state by one byte.

Comment: Falling into a cycle short enough to be recognizable as a cycle is fantastically unlikely. From a practical perspective, repeated SHA256 does not cycle.

Comment: "and std::copy() the memory" - "std::memcpy" probably

Comment: @Sneftel It's not the same as repeated SHA256, it shifts one new byte in at a time. *Probably* it is still fantastically unlikely, but why risk it when it can be avoided entirely?

Comment: @G.Sliepen why would you expect that to have a significantly different expected cycle length than repeated SHA256? That would only be the case if SHA256 is broken.

Comment: @Sneftel It is extremely dangerous to *assume* that some construct built on top of SHA256 is safe just because SHA256 is safe. I've learned that lesson in the past. While what OP did *looks* safe to me as well, I don't want to spend effort *proving* that when it can avoided altogether.

Comment: @G.Sliepen fair enough. The safety seems intuitive to me, but I agree that it’s an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 24):

Your question has two parts:

1. Is the *algorithm* good?
2. Is the *implementation* good?

The first part is not really the purview of code review, because it is not only a mathematical question, it is an *extremely complex* mathematical question.

Designing a new pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) algorithm is not a simple thing. One cannot simply look at the code of a PRNG and determine whether it is good or bad. To evaluate a PRNG, you need a room full of PhD’s, all using advanced statistical techniques, running weeks of tests on supercomputers. And *then* you need to publish those results in scholarly journals for peer review. There’s a reason PRNGs are named after their inventors; it’s a big deal when you actually invent a good one.

So there is no possible way I can even begin to evaluate whether your idea is good or not. I know *nothing* about the PRNG’s characteristics—what is it’s period, for example? I’d need to run weeks of tests to even figure out if it actually generates anything even approximating randomness at all.

So no one here can possibly review the quality of the *design*. What we can do is review this particular implementation. That won’t help much if the algorithm is hot garbage; even a perfect implementation of a garbage algorithm is still garbage.

I can note this much though: While a 32-byte state is relatively small… it’s hardly “tiny”. Both `std::minstd_rand` and `std::minstd_rand0` have only something like a single `std::uint_fast32_t` of state (which is 4 or 8 bytes, usually). And among non-standard PRNGs, the excellent `taus88` PRNG—available in Boost, for example—has only 12 bytes of state, is super-fast, and has a decent period considering its tiny size.

I would also point out that you’re misrepresenting the size of the state when you say it’s only 32 bytes… because you’re not counting the size of the state of the SHA256 implementation. Granted, that’s ephemeral, but it’s not zero. And it’s not trivial.

## Design review

My biggest objection to the design is that it doesn’t conform to the standard PRNG interface… making it practically useless in general. I can’t use it in [`shuffle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/shuffle), for example, and I can’t use it with any distributions (what if I want a normal distribution, for example).

It isn’t hard to make a standard-conforming PRNG. [The concept only requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_random_bit_generator):

1. a `result_type`
2. a static `min()` function
3. a static `max()` function; and
4. `operator()`.

Aside from that, most of the problems with the design here stem from the SHA256 implementation. In other words, wherever the code here is bad, it’s usually due to the crappy SHA256 interface. I mean, seriously… returning a raw owning pointer? What is this, 1985?

Also, the fact that the SHA256 implementation allocates memory is pretty much going to kill any performance dreams you might have.

Using a better SHA256 implementation would fix most of the problems, but even if using hardware SHA256 support (via intrinsics) I suspect it will still be fairly slow.

## Code review

```
        std::array<uint8_t, 32>
            m_state;
```

That should be `std::uint8_t`. And you should include the appropriate header: `<cstdint>`.

```
        random_engine_t(const uint8_t* seed, size_t slen);
```

You don’t specify what version of C++ you’re targeting, so I’ll assume the current version: C++20.

Taking a pointer and a size is old school. In modern C++, you should prefer iterators or ranges… preferably the latter.

*Theoretically*, you only need an input range… but because of the SHA256 interface, you’re forced to require a *contiguous* range. (Or you could take an input range, and if it’s not contiguous, copy it into a vector, and then that use that with the SHA256 interface. Yeah, that’s ugly, but… as I said, it’s a crappy interface.)

So if you’re forced to use a contiguous range, you could take it, wrap it in a `span`, and then use `as_bytes()` to get a view of the raw bytes, and pass that to the SHA256 interface.

That alone would be the only constructor you should need.

```
        random_engine_t(const char* seed);
```

First, this should definitely be `explicit`.

Second, I don’t see the point of taking a C-string rather than a `string_view`, which would not only handle *any* kind of string, it would even be significantly faster in most cases, because you wouldn’t need to get the size.

But of course, a `string_view` is also a contiguous range, so it could be handled by a generic contiguous range constructor.

```
        random_engine_t(const time_t seed);
```

Again, should be explicit.

Also, should be `std::time_t`, and you need the proper header.

But from a design standpoint, this constructor seems like a bad idea, because it is generally advised *not* to seed PRNGs with the time. It’s bad for security, and it’s bad if the program may be run several times in quick succession (`std::time_t` often only has a precision of one second… which pretty huge in computer time). With the standard random library, the common practice is to seed using `std::random_device`, which is (hopefully) a non-deterministic hardware entropy source.

If someone doesn’t care and really wants to seed the time, fine… but that doesn’t mean you should make it easy.

```
        template<typename T>
        T next() {
            static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 32);
```

You mentioned that `T` should be an integral type, but you do nothing to enforce it. If you have `static_assert()`, you have `std::is_integral`… and if you have `static_assert()` without a message, then you have `std::is_integral_v`. You could easily add `static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>)`.

As of C++20, though, a better option would be to use the `std::integral` concept.

```
            SHA256 sha; sha.update(m_state.data(), m_state.size());
```

Don’t jam multiple statements together. One statement per line, please.

```
            uint8_t* digest = sha.digest();
```

Alright, so you’re stuck using an API that actually returns an owning raw pointer. That’s terrible, but you shouldn’t make the situation worse. You should immediately put that owning raw pointer into a smart pointer. `delete` is a code smell.

So this line should be something like:

```
auto digest = std::unique_ptr<std::uint8_t[]>{sha.digest()};
```

And, of course, remove the `delete[]` line.

```
            T t = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(digest);
```

You have a bug here. You cannot assume the memory allocated by the SHA256 interface is appropriately aligned for a `T`. That cast (or the subsequent access) may trigger a fault on some hardware. In general, `reinterpret_cast` is a code smell.

Just do `auto t = T{};`, then copy the bytes from the digest into `t`.

```
                //shuffle back
                for (size_t s = 1; s < m_state.size(); s++) {
                    m_state[s - 1] = m_state[s];
                }
```

Don’t write raw `for` loops, especially when it’s just a standard algorithm. In this case, that loop is just [`std::ranges::shift_left(m_state, 1);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/shift).

```
                m_state[m_state.size() - 1] = digest[0];
```

This would be much more readable as just `m_state.back() = digest[0];`.

And, also:

```
            std::copy(digest, digest + 32, m_state.data());
```

This could be simpler with `copy_n()`.

Comment: It's not so much that evaluating a "good PRNG" is mathematically difficult, it's more that it's an ill-specified problem. For many monte carlo algorithms, even RANDU is actually perfectly ok to use, although it's from a modern perspective a catastrophically bad PRNG. The current standard PRNGs are good for current applications, but it may well happen that a completely new sort of domain arises in 10 years where they turn out to be unusable (perhaps some AI adversarial issue or so).

Comment: "So there is no possible way I can even begin to evaluate whether your idea is good or not."
It is true that you cannot begin to evaluate if the idea is good, but it is very easy to demonstrate that this idea is bad.  The current implementation allows the caller complete knowledge of internal state after 32 calls. That's bad.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm sorry but I don't see why leaking the internal state is an issue. Anyone who has knowledge of the header knows where the state data is situated and can copy it with a simple `memcpy`. Care to enlighten me? If that's really an issue, one could use `m_state.back() = (digest[0] ^ 0xff);`... I guess.

Comment: Well, in a video game, that means a character only needs to do 32 things that use the RNG, and then from then on, they can accurately predict every "random" thing that happens for the rest of the game. hit/miss/crit, the next card in the deck, etc.  It gets even worse if you try to use this PRNG for anything involving security. This is a hacker's dream come true.